# React: "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'" for TypeScript decorators from NestJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I would like to share types between React (create-react-app) frontend and NestJs backend. I use `class-validator` for validating DTOs in NestJs, but when I import these classes into React app, it throws an error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (4:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I am trying with `react-app-rewired` and adding plugins to .babelrc:

```
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
```

It doesn't help and I have the same error.

I also tried npm package `react-class-validator` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-class-validator, but the result is the same.

How should I configure React app to be able handle classes with typescript decorators from NestJs?